# PyCharm python file consists of only one line instead of normal editor

Tags: python, pycharm

I just installed PyCharm on my Mac and it looks like this when I edit or create a new Python file:

[image: Editor_current]

This is how the file looks like in TextEdit:
[image: Pyfile_current]

How can I change it so it looks normal again? (Like this:)
[image: Editor_normal]

For whatever reason only one line is shown and I can't find an option to increase the number of lines that are displayed anywhere.

Comment: There is only one line in the file? If you add more lines then more lines will be displayed, this behaviour is normal

Comment: Yeah but how do I do it? And why does it look this way in the first place?

Comment: How do you write lines of code?

Comment: It is not possible to write any code when you can only see one line of code that‘s why I asking how to change it

Comment: Have you used a text editor before? Hit the return key to add a new line

Comment: I‘m using PyCharm for 2 years now on PC and this never happened. Yes of course I did press enter. In fact this file consists of about 50 lines of code but it only shows the first line and I can‘t even scroll trough the lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed the error myself. The latest version of PyCharm is buggy. Installing an older version of it fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
Close every file individually, then close PyCharm.

After opening PyCharm back up, opening the project from Open Recent seemed to resolve the issue for me.

Comment: I found closing that project window and reopening worked for me. However, it does appear to be slightly buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I updated to the fresh version 2021.2.1 and the problem went away.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried writing more lines of code?

in pycharm `unused` imports are always in grey color, until the import is used.

So just continue writing your code it will become normal.